# React Native Expo app giving an error with axios [AxiosError: Network Error]

Tags: mongodb, react-native, axios, expo

I am following a tutorial on how to make an app with mongoDB and expo router, however when using axios I am getting the error [AxiosError: Network Error].I will be listing the code of the function being called for axios and the api file.

function being called:

```
const adddetails = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [employeeId, setEmployeeId] = useState('')
  const [dob, setDob] = useState('')
  const [mobileNo, setMobileNo] = useState('')
  const [joiningDate, setJoiningDate] = useState('')
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState('')
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
  const [designation, setDesignation] = useState('')

  const handleRegister = () => {
    const employeeData = {
      employeeName: name,
      employeeId: employeeId,
      designation: designation,
      phoneNumber: mobileNo,
      dateOfBirth: dob,
      joiningData: joiningDate,
      activeEmployee: true,
      salary: salary,
      address: address
    }

    axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/addEmployee', employeeData)
      .then((response) => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Regestration was successful',
          'You have been registered successfully'
        )
        setName('')
        setEmployeeId('')
        setDob('')
        setMobileNo('')
        setJoiningDate('')
        setSalary('')
        setAddress('')
        setDesignation('')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert('Registration Fail', 'An error occured during registration')
        console.log('registration has failed', error)
      })
  }
```

(Axios and Alert is already imported)

api file

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()
const port = 8000
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose
  .connect('mongodb+srv://MONGODBDATA@cluster0.z4ombav.mongodb.net/', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB', error)
  })

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 8000')
})

const Employee = require('./models/employee')
const Attendance = require('./models/attendance')

// End point to register an employee
app.post('/addEmployee', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      employeeName,
      employeeId,
      designation,
      phoneNumber,
      dateOfBirth,
      joiningDate,
      activeEmployee,
      salary,
      address
    } = req.body

    // Create a new employee
    const newEmployee = new Employee({
      employeeName,
      employeeId,
      designation,
      phoneNumber,
      dateOfBirth,
      joiningDate,
      activeEmployee,
      salary,
      address
    })

    await newEmployee.save()

    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: 'Employee saved successfuly', employee: newEmployee })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error registering employee', error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to add an employee' })
  }
})

// endpoint to fetch all the employees
app.get('/employees', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employees = await Employee.find()
    res.status(200).json(employees)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to retrieve the employees' })
  }
})
```

I am getting all of the console.logs like the server running on port 8000 and connected to MongoDB

I have tried changing the url on the axios.post from localhost to 10.0.2.2
I have also tried changing the url on the axios.post from localhost to my ipaddress from my command prompt ipconfig.

Comment: I think, even I'm facing the same error, tried using --tunnel with npm but still the API does not work from my mobile device. Teh same API works absolutely fine on web but not on the expo app on my mobile.